# update empty array fields in mongodb

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I am trying to update my array which has fields in it. The array is already saved in the database, but without the fields in it. Is there a way to update the empty array and add fields in it

Schema

```
      const UserSchema = new Schema({
        User: [{

         Name:{
           type: String,
        },

        Email:{
           type: String,
        },

       }]
    })
```

The array is already saved in the database but its empty like this

saved database

```
      "id": 101,
      "User":[],
```

Here is the code i used to update the array

```
           User.update({id: 101,},
             {
             $push:{
                 user:{
                      Name: "Kevin",
                      Email: "Kevin@gmail.com",
                     },
                   }
             },(err, data)=>{
                console.log(data)
             })
```

Every time I run the code the array doesn't update, does anyone know how to go about this problem?

Comment: Could it be because the object has a capitalized "U" while the query does not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.getCollection('test2').update({
  "id": 101
},
{
  $push: {
    User: {
      $each: [
        {
          "name": "gibbs"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Update array using `$each`. And `User` should be capital as fields are case sensitive in mongo.

[Refer](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)

**Output:**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f08753ce96d8884b6bcc92e"),
    "id" : 101,
    "User" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "gibbs"
        }
    ]
}
```